# Display count of grouped points on Highcharts dataGrouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart with some points which displays a value and they are sorted by datetime. I want to group the points by days and show the total number of points per day, not the sum of their values.

Highcharts provides any option to display count of grouped points when I use `dataGrouping`? Or I have to do this operation with javascript or on server side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataGrouping allows you to write a callback function for the approximation. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

```
    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur,
        dataGrouping: {
            approximation: function(arr) {
                return arr.length;
            },
            forced: true
        }
    }]
```

Be sure to turn `forced: true` on to make sure that the function is always called.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzbnh6wv/  Zoom out to see the count go up per group.